# Why Pearson correlation is different between Tensorflow and Scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, scipy, metrics

I compute the Pearson correlation in 2 ways :

---

In Tensorflow, I use the following metric :

```
tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation(y_pred, y_true)
```

When I evaluate my network on test data, I got following results :

> loss = 0.5289223349094391
>
> pearson = 0.3701728057861328

*(Loss is `mean_squared_error`)*

---

Then I predict the test data and compute the same metrics with Scipy :

```
import scipy.stats as measures
per_coef = measures.pearsonr(y_pred, y_true)[0]
mse_coef = np.mean(np.square(np.array(y_pred) - np.array(y_true)))
```

And I get following results :

> Pearson = 0.5715300096509959
>
> MSE = 0.5289223312665985

---

**Is it a known issue ? Is it normal ?**

## Minimal, complete and verifiable example

```
import tensorflow as tf
import scipy.stats as measures

y_pred = [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2]
y_true = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

## Scipy
val2 = measures.pearsonr(y_pred, y_true)[0]
print("Scipy's Pearson = {}".format(val2))

## Tensorflow
logits = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [8])
labels = tf.to_float(tf.Variable(y_true))

acc, acc_op = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation(logits,labels)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(acc, {logits:y_pred})
sess.run(acc_op, {logits:y_pred})

print("Tensorflow's Pearson:{}".format(sess.run(acc,{logits:y_pred})))
```

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Do you see a similar difference with a simple dataset such as `y_pred = [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2]`, `y_true = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`?

Comment: I see a difference, but much smaller. Do you think this small difference is in cause ? And why there is a difference at all ?

Comment: The pearson correlation in your mcve is `0.3806076...` for both tensorflow and scipy in every one of my tests.

Comment: Yes, the difference is after these digits for me too.

Comment: What happens if you run the tensorflow code using `float64` instead of `float32`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the minimal verifiable example you gave, `y_pred` and `y_true` are lists of integers. In the first line of the `scipy.stats.measures.pearsonr` [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L2392), you will see that the inputs are converted to numpy arrays with `x = np.asarray(x)`. We can see the resulting data types of these arrays via:

```
print(np.asarray(y_pred).dtype)  # Prints 'int64'
```

When dividing two `int64` numbers, SciPy uses `float64` precision, while TensorFlow will use `float32` precision in the example above. The difference can be quite large, even for a single division:

```
>>> '%.15f' % (8.5 / 7)
'1.214285714285714'
>>> '%.15f' % (np.array(8.5, dtype=np.float32) / np.array(7, dtype=np.float32))
'1.214285731315613'
>>> '%.15f' % (np.array(8.5, dtype=np.float32) / np.array(7, dtype=np.float32) - 8.5 / 7)
'0.000000017029899'
```

You can get the same results for SciPy and TensorFlow by using `float32` precision for `y_pred` and `y_true`:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import scipy.stats as measures

y_pred = np.array([2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2], dtype=np.float32)
y_true = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=np.float32)

## Scipy
val2 = measures.pearsonr(y_pred, y_true)[0]
print("Scipy's Pearson: \t\t{}".format(val2))

## Tensorflow
logits = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [8])
labels = tf.to_float(tf.Variable(y_true))

acc, acc_op = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation(logits,labels)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(acc, {logits:y_pred})
sess.run(acc_op, {logits:y_pred})

print("Tensorflow's Pearson: \t{}".format(sess.run(acc,{logits:y_pred})))
```

prints

```
Scipy's Pearson:        0.38060760498046875
Tensorflow's Pearson:   0.38060760498046875
```

### Differences between SciPy's and TensorFlow's computation

In the test scores you report, the difference is quite high. I took a look at the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/contrib/metrics/python/ops/metric_ops.py#L3300) and found the following differences:

#### 1. Update ops

The result of `tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation` is not stateless. It returns the correlation coefficient op, together with an `update_op` for new incoming data. If you call the update op with different data before calling the coefficient op with the actual `y_pred`, it will give a completely different result:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for _ in range(20):
    sess.run(acc_op, {logits: np.random.randn(*y_pred.shape)})

print("Tensorflow's Pearson: \t{}".format(sess.run(acc,{logits:y_pred})))
```

prints

```
Scipy's Pearson:        0.38060760498046875
Tensorflow's Pearson:   -0.0678008571267128
```

#### 2. Different formulae

SciPy:

[image]

TensorFlow:

[image]

While mathematically the same, the computation of the correlation coefficient is different in TensorFlow. It uses the sample covariance for (x, x), (x, y) and (y, y) to compute the correlation coefficient, which can introduce different rounding errors.

Comment: Very interesting answer, a lot of precisions. Thanks for the clarification !